# Default timezone for all docker containers

Tags: docker

I am using Ubuntu OS. Using below command I can see the date and time when a container was created.

```
$ docker inspect httpd | grep Created
  Created": "2019-09-22T05:46:42.109648817Z",
```

I can see my local system timezone using below command

```
$ cat /etc/timezone 
Asia/Kolkata
```

As you see my system timezone is set to `Asia/Kolkata` but the the time shown using docker inspect command seems to be in UTC.

I have also re-configured my system timezone using below command to `Asia/Kolkata`:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
Current default time zone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
Local time is now:      Sun Sep 22 11:27:05 IST 2019.
Universal Time is now:  Sun Sep 22 05:57:05 UTC 2019.
```

Still when I create a new container it's creation time is shown in UTC.

How I can configure my system in such a way that for any existing or newly created container, creation time is shown as per my system timezone settings.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `TZ` option in docker run command
like

```
docker run -rm -e TZ=Europe/Bucharest -it myimage
```

this will assign timezone whatever you want inside docker container

Comment: I'd assume that only works for Unix-based images, but that's probably the majority of them.

Comment: I have removed the container and tried `docker container run --rm --publish 8080:80 --name httpd -d -e "TZ=Asia/Kolkata" httpd` but still the created date is shown according to UTC. One more thing, I would like to set it as default on docker configuration level so that I do not have to set it for each container.

Comment: try to open container in bash mode and check the DateTime it returns. Because it might be possible the created date of the container is showing according to UTC time!

Comment: I opened it in bash using `docker exec -it httpd bash` and there if I use `date` it shows time in IST which is fine. But the creation date using inspect command shows in UTC.

Comment: host is linux or windows?

Comment: I found a discussion on docker fourm and the one is using windows machine. He tried other was which is not preferable but worked "Using volumes" have a look https://forums.docker.com/t/synchronize-timezone-from-host-to-container/39116/5

Comment: Host is linux (Ubunut 18.04).

Answer (score 0):

Its really annoying that sometimes it is referred as Kolkata and sometimes Calcutta here it is `Asia/Calcutta`